# Send an email to all the users on Firebase from Authentication list

Tags: android, email, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way for me to send an email to all the users that are in my Authentication list.
I know that I can send email on the beginning (Email address verification)
but this is not a case.
I made a new update to an app and I want to send an email explaining what went wrong.

Comment: You can't. BUT if you keep the users informations in a node, then you can.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is over two years old at this point, but for anyone new coming across this -

Firebase now provides [Extensions](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/), one of which addresses this issue:
https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/auth-mailchimp-sync/

This extension automatically generates cloud-functions which adds new users to a specified Mailchimp audience, and removes them if they delete their account.

If you have existing users that you wish to add first, then use the approach to list all users emails via the Admin SDK that @Doug Stevenson outlined previously.

Answer (score 6):

Your best option (and maybe only option) is to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) and apply its [User Management features](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) to [list all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).  Once you have that list, you can use that to send your own email.  Firebase will not send the email for you.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit 26'th January 2022**

Firebase released an extension called [Trigger Email Extension from Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-send-email) that can help achieve what you want. To implement this extension please follow the steps that are explained in the following article:

- [How to install and use Trigger Email Extension from Firebase?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-install-and-use-trigger-email-extension-from-firebase-f6f9763c8088)

---

Firebase does not provide a newsletter service. The only way you can send an email to a user is when you are verifying the email address within the authentication process. To achieve what you want, you need to get the list of the emails of your users and use a third-party app that allows you to send bulk emails but be aware of spam email regulations.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a node server(which is kinda weird if you are using firebase to store information but I do have it for sockets and routes), you can achieve this using firebase admin sdk and then retrieving all the users and sending mails through nodemailer.
But in my case what I was doing was weird and make sure you are not doing the same thibg: I was using socket for sending all the list of users. I know this is weird but back then, I didn't know about admin sdk and api get requests.